# Is versioning user profiles feasible?

Tags: profile, git

I recently tried to version a lot of things that weren't versioned in Git just yet. But even with the now-used source format, it seems there is still some metadata that is particularly prone to the *morphing XML* phenomena - that is XML that will constantly "change" (read: look different) every time it is pulled from Salesforce.

Is there any way to version profiles without generating non-existent changes? Is it even a good idea to version them? Are there other components that suffer from the same problem?

Comment: I'd drop the concept of tracking profiles in general, in preference to tracking Permission Sets and Perm Set Groups. There are some oddities around profile retrieval - e.g. a profile includes permissions for objects retrieved in the same command, but not others - that could be what's biting you.

Comment: Indeed - that's one of the reasons why I really don't like working with profiles in Git.

Comment: And to anyone downvoting my question - please provide some constructive feedback about how my question is unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to version profiles without generating non-existent changes?

I don't think so, unfortunately.

> Is it even a good idea to version them?

This depends on your use case. Generally speaking, it is not worth it to version profiles because of the reason you mentioned. It is one of the biggest drivers to move to Permission Sets, actually.

You might get off just versioning them for compliance reasons, but not using the metadata for important things. I find that it is much more useful to version flows, Apex and database schema (objects/fields) than things like profiles. But again: you might need to do that because of compliance reasons (to know who had access to something at a specific time).